# How to join a workgroup computer to a domain remotely

Tags: vbscript, dns, workgroup, ou

Scenario: I'm using ComputerA in a domain with admin credentials. Remote ComputerB (with known admin credentials) is in a workgroup. ComputerB needs to join a specific domain (Different than ComputerA's) in a specified OU which my active ComputerA credentials have the rights to do. I Cannot use an external program such as NETDOM and would prefer to use VBScript.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to resolve this on my own. Here's the code for future coders:

```
Const JOIN_DOMAIN             = 1
Const ACCT_CREATE             = 2
Const ACCT_DELETE             = 4
Const WIN9X_UPGRADE           = 16
Const DOMAIN_JOIN_IF_JOINED   = 32
Const JOIN_UNSECURE           = 64
Const MACHINE_PASSWORD_PASSED = 128
Const DEFERRED_SPN_SET        = 256
Const INSTALL_INVOCATION      = 262144

Const WbemAuthenticationLevelPktPrivacy = 6

SystemName = "ComputerB"
strNamespace = "root\cimv2"
ComputerBLogin= "Login"
ComputerBPass = "Password"
ComputerALogin = "Login"
ComputerAPass = "Password"
DomainName = "domain.com"
OU = "OU=desiredou,DC=domain,DC=com"

Set objWbemLocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")

Set objWMIService = objwbemLocator.ConnectServer(SystemName, strNamespace, ComputerBLogin, ComputerBPass)

objWMIService.Security_.authenticationLevel = WbemAuthenticationLevelPktPrivacy

Set colComputers = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * From Win32_ComputerSystem")
For Each objComputer in colComputers
    ReturnValue = objComputer.JoinDomainOrWorkGroup(DomainName, ComputerAPass, ComputerALogin, OU, JOIN_DOMAIN + ACCT_CREATE)
Next

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    message = WshShell.Popup ("Unable to join " & SystemName & " to the domain! Please join manually.",, "Error", 0 + 16)
Else
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    message = WshShell.Popup ("Domain joining was successful!",, "Success!", 0 + 64)
End If

Err.Clear
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i adapted a piece of script from http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1240726

```
strComputer = "ComputerB"
strPassword = "mypassword"
strDomain   = "mydomain"
strUser     = "myusername"

Set objComputer = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=Impersonate}!\\" & _
    strComputer & "\root\cimv2:Win32_ComputerSystem.Name='" & _
        strComputer & "'")

ReturnValue = objComputer.JoinDomainOrWorkGroup(strDomain, strPassword, strDomain & "\" & strUser, "ou=My_Computer_OU,DC=mycorp,dc=com, _
        JOIN_DOMAIN + ACCT_CREATE)

If ReturnValue = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Computer added to domain under old name without error. proceeding to change computer name. "
Else
    MsgBox "Computer not added to domain successfully. Return value: " & ReturnValue
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but ended up figuring it out on my own.

Comment: then accept one of the answers please, otherwise people who want to help keep opening this question

Comment: I tried to originally, but for some reason it made me wait 3 hours before I could actually check it. And as I didn't have 3 hours to sit around, I naturally forgot about it. Should be checked now.